# Remove specific cookie on firefox

Tags: firefox, user-interface, cookies

I am doing some testing of firefox and got myself into situation where I need some cookies to be present while some others to be removed. I could write javascript that would do this, but was wondering if there is a way to do it via UI, like it can be done on Chrome dev tools, since testers are non technical and they will need to do it too

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I remove specific cookies on firefox

You can do this with the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/) extension, which adds various web developer tools to the browser.

1. Right click on page
2. Select `Web Developer`
3. Select `Cookies
4. Select `View Cookie Information`

   [image]
5. The resulting tab/window has options to `Delete` and `Edit` the cookies for the current web page.

   [image]

Comment: I have asked same question on StackOverflow before asking it here, if you would copy over this answer it's easy 35 rep. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335004/remove-specific-cookie-on-firefox

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius Done ;)